# Trouble converting a google calendar JSON feed into an array for Simple Calendar input

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to grab some json data from Google Calendar and feed it into a jquery plugin called "Simple Events Calendar"

The plugin expects something like this:

```
var events_array = new Array(
{
    startDate: new Date(2014,02,12,17,30),
    endDate: new Date(2014,02,12,18,0),
    title: 'eventName',
    description: 'eventSummary',
    priority: 3, // 1 = Low, 2 = Medium, 3 = Urgent
    frequency: 1 // 1 = Daily, 2 = Weekly, 3 = Monthly, 4 = Yearly
},
{
    startDate: new Date(2014,02,10,20,50),
    endDate: new Date(2014,02,10,20,59),
    title: "Event 2",
    description: "Description 2",
    priority: 1,
    frequency:1
},
{
    startDate: new Date(2014,07,20,18,0),
    endDate: new Date(2014,00,20,21,30),
    title: "Event 3",
    description: "Description 3",
    priority: 3,
    frequency:1
}
);
```

I'm grabbing and parsing the data like this:

```
var urllist =  ["http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/events%40wilsonabbey.com/public/full?        orderby=starttime&sortorder=ascending&max-results=3&futureevents=true&alt=json"];
var JSONData = { count: 0,
    value : {
        description: "Wilson Abbey Events",
        generator: "StackOverflow communal coding",
        items: []
}};

urllist.forEach(function addFeed(url){
    $.getJSON(url, complete);
});

function complete(result, status, jqXHR) {
    var eventName = [];
    var eventSummary = [];
    var data_element = '';
        var events_array = new Array();
    // Track the number of calls completed back, we're not done until all 3
    // asynchronous calls have returned
    if( typeof complete.count === 'undefined' )
        complete.count = urllist.length;

    if(!result.feed.entry) {
        console.log("No entries from ");
    } else {
        JSONData.count += result.feed.entry.length;
    JSONData.value.items = JSONData.value.items.concat(result.feed.entry);
}
//console.log(complete.count);
if (!(--complete.count)) {
    console.log(JSONData);
    var str = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < JSONData.value.items.length; i++) {
        var item = JSONData.value.items[i];
        str += item.author[0].name.$t + " (starts " + item.gd$when[0].startTime + "): " + item.title.$t + "\n";
        eventName[i] = item.title.$t;
        eventSummary[i] = item.content.$t;
        dataItem = 'startDate: new Date(2014,02,12,17,30),';
        dataItem += 'endDate: new Date(2014,02,12,18,0),';
        dataItem += 'title: ' + eventName[i] + ',';
        dataItem += 'description: ' + eventSummary[i] + ',';
        dataItem += 'priority: 3,';
        dataItem += 'frequency: 1';
        events_array[i] = dataItem;
        }
        console.log(events_array);
        $("#calendar").dp_calendar({
            events_array: events_array
        });

        }
}
```

Most of the code was helpfully provided by the community here, mostly the problem I
am having is putting the data into a format Simple Events Calendar will accept.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Rick Mills

But I get the error (from console)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getHours' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - I needed to create an array of objects and I was creating an array of string literals.

New code replaced in for loop:

```
var obj = {
startDate: new Date(2014,02,14,17,30),
endDate: new Date(2014,02,14,18,0),
title: item.title.$t,
description: 'eventSummary',
priority: 3, // 1 = Low, 2 = Medium, 3 = Urgent
frequency: 1 // 1 = Daily, 2 = Weekly, 3 = Monthly, 4 = Yearly
};
events_array.push(obj);
```